# make 3 rows, 1 column from 1 row 3 colums

Tags: sql, db2, unpivot

I have following table in db2:

| id | person 1 | person 2 | person 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 12 | 15 |

I now want to make a query that returns the following:

| id | person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 15 |

how can I do this in db2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more efficiently not to scan the same potentially large table multiple times.
Try this:

```
SELECT T.ID, V.PERSON
FROM MYTAB T, TABLE (VALUES T.PERSON1, T.PERSON2, T.PERSON3) V (PERSON);
```

Comment: it has indeed much better performance, ty!

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION:

```
select id, person1 as person
from the_table
union all 
select id, person2
from the_table
union all 
select id, person3
from the_table
```